# How can I learn the specific reason someone else's question is put "on hold"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I see that [Project Euler 11 Wrong Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28525769/3001761) has been put on hold by a single person, a moderator. The conditions for doing so - as stated below the question - aren't really evident to me: the code to reproduce is all there, and the expected result is (at least indirectly) well-defined. So I would like to learn why this question really has been put on hold - let's say just so I can better vote to put other questions on hold, too.

In this particular case, it's a question from a competition where everybody should work on her/his own. But if this is the "hidden" reason for "on hold", it should be stated in a comment (*"We don't answer questions from competitions."*)

It is not a request for code review, as has been suggested (when I previously asked this question on MSE).

It also has been suggested that the hold is due to a *"lack of effort"* or *"absence of a description of the debug effort"*. This is clearly the case in 90% of all questions, and if this should be a reason for the hold, it should deserve an explicit statement.

Comment: 'This is clearly the case in 90% of all questions' - then 90% of all questions should be closed.  It  is a waste of contributor resources to apply the same comment to 90% of all input, just as it's a waste for resources for mutiple contribitors to be asked to copy/paste/build/compile/debug in parallel, just so that the first to answer gets internet points, and the rest waste their time.

Comment: @MartinJames I agree, *but* (!) not without telling the OP *as accurately as possible* why it was closed. SO should make it clear to all concerned whether or not it is prepared to help amateurs, 1st grade studens and dummies, and where the line is drawn.

Comment: What *"other meta-site"* are you referring to? Also, note that SO puts *"professional and enthusiast programmers"* right at the top of the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [on-topic guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @jonrsharpe it was posted earlier on MSE where we suggested to post on MSO (we closed it for that reason)

Comment: I would also point out that the close reason *does* accurately tell the OP why the question was closed, per the analysis in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only Bohemian can say for sure why they closed it, but I would have done the same. The close reason in question is:

> "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

So how does that question score against the three items it **must** include?

1. *"the desired behaviour"* - **yes**, the expected output is included;
2. *"a specific problem or error"* - **no**, the actual output or error message is not included, all the OP says is *"does not give me the right answer"*; and
3. *"the shortest code necessary"* - **no**, the OP has just dumped their whole code in, without any obvious attempt to reduce it down to the actual source of the problem.

1/3 is not good enough to keep it open.

Comment: What would you omit there without creating additional bugs? And the actual output is clearly not in any way helpful. (One should apply rules with a little savvy, I think.)

Comment: @laune as a starting point, I would create a smaller input sample, and test each loop separately to ensure that all of adjacent sets I'm expecting are being tested by the code. That way I can at least narrow it down to a single  `for` loop (or absence thereof). The actual output (in terms of the adjacent set found, if not necessarily the total) *is* useful - has the code found the largest vertically-adjacent subset but not the total largest, for example?

Comment: *That* is a constructive approach one should take, and **this comment** (plus one other statement) would be the answer I'd give there, if it weren't closed down...

Comment: @laune you could spend all day writing *"here's how to debug this code"* on low-effort questions, which will only encourage more to be posted, or just point them to e.g. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and move on to someone who's put some work in.

Comment: You would have checked (how? manually?) whether the wrong number would result from a vertical or horizontal or \-ish row??

Comment: @laune as I say, by creating a smaller input sample. Also, by tweaking the code to `println` each adjacent set as it's found rather than just calculating the product. But this isn't the appropriate venue to teach debugging!

Comment: "spend all day..." - this is what actually happens. The discouragement - as it is perhaps going on - doesn't work. This *may* be due for just what I'm trying to pinpoint here: how should OP learn to make it better next time?

Comment: @laune that is **also in the close reason** - the OP should read the (very helpful) article on creating an MCVE, which even links to the above blog post on debugging. If the OP reads the close reason and applies the information that it provides, they will be well on their way to improving the question enough for reopening. It's worth noting that the same advice is available on [*"How to Ask"*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - pre-emptive effort on the OP's part would have kept them from the downvotes and closure (or, possibly, from needing to ask at all).

Comment: To summarize and conclude, only MCVE Qs from "professionals and enthusiasts" (let's hope we can distinguish them *clearly* from the rest) should be answered. Neither help nor hint as comment or answer is indicated. (Which would lead me to another question: What about those that do answer Qs not deserving an A, clearly counteracting SO's declared intent?)

Comment: @laune I've already demonstrated that your premise (that the close reason doesn't give the OP sufficient information) is faulty (it gives plenty of *"hint"*). Comments aren't needed, and answers to bad questions aren't helpful (IMO, but that's a whole other topic of discussion). An MCVE is a must for *this specific class of question*, not *every* question (although they're almost always helpful, which is why they're in How to Ask). Distinguishing professionals and enthusiasts *is* difficult, so here's a rule of thumb: did the OP put in any effort beyond the typing? Any evidence of research?